# Raise the power of a Sparse Matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a sparse matrix of 10001 rows + 10001 columns (with many 0's),

I am trying to raise the power of this sparse matrix

i.e.

```
A = [[1,1],[1,0]]
AS = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
AS

def matrixMul(AS, n):
    if(n <= 1):
        return AS
    else:
        return np.matmul(matrixMul(AS, n-1), AS)

matrixMul(AS, 10)
```

Expected result if I raise AS to the power of 2 should be
[[2, 1]
[1, 1]]

I would like to find AS ^ 10

What function should I call? I have tried the code above but received this error.

Thank you.

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 9         return np.matmul(matrixMul(AS, n-1), AS)
> 10
> ---> 11 matrixMul(AS, 10)
>
> 8 frames  in matrixMul(AS, n)
> 7         return AS
> 8     else:
> ----> 9         return np.matmul(matrixMul(AS, n-1), AS)
> 10
> 11 matrixMul(AS, 10)
>
> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions
> (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

Comment: The error says that at some point in the recursion that one argument to `matmul` is 0d, i.e. a scalar, or maybe a single element object dtype array.  Test that `matrixMul` with a much smaller `n`, before going to the full 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power operator: `AS ** 10` is the same as `AS ^ 10` in normal mathematic notation.

```
def matrixMul(AS, n):
    if(n <= 1):
        return AS
    else:
        return AS ** n
```

Comment: I think i was unclear, I am looking for dot.product instead of element wise

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: from scipy import sparse
In [4]: A = [[1,1],[1,0]]
   ...: AS = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
In [5]: AS
Out[5]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [6]: AS.A
Out[6]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 0]])
In [7]: (AS@AS@AS).A
Out[7]: 
array([[3, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

`@` maps to `AS.__matmul__`, but `np.matmul` does not delegate it that way.

```
In [8]: np.matmul(AS,AS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-37972b025121>", line 1, in <module>
    np.matmul(AS,AS)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
```

Correction:

```
In [9]: def matrixMul(AS, n):
   ...:     if(n <= 1):
   ...:         return AS
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return matrixMul(AS, n-1)@ AS
   ...: 
In [10]: matrixMul(AS,3)
Out[10]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [11]: _.A
Out[11]: 
array([[3, 2],
       [2, 1]])
In [12]: matrixMul(AS,10).A
Out[12]: 
array([[89, 55],
       [55, 34]])
```

As shown in comments, the `**` power works:

```
In [15]: (AS**10).A
Out[15]: 
array([[89, 55],
       [55, 34]])
```

Sparse matrix is modeled on `np.matrix`.  `*` is matrix multiplication, and `**` is matrix power.

This power times about the same as this semi-smart explicit multiplication:

```
def foo(AS):
    AS2=AS@AS
    return AS2@AS2@AS2@AS2@AS2
In [33]: timeit foo(AS).A
865 µs ± 378 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [34]: timeit AS**10
767 µs ± 189 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: The correction worked well for me! can I ask why did you do a .A at the end? Referring to this part --> matrixMul(AS,10).A

Comment: `.A` is shorthand for `.toarray()`, displaying the matrix as dense array.

Comment: thank you! that cleared my doubt. Could I also ask if it is possible to multiply 2 sparse matrix together?

Comment: what do the docs say?